# querying based on foreign key's value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these 3 tables:

- `metric` - id, name, machine_id (FK to machine), createdAt
- `metric_value` - timestamp, metric_id (FK to metric), value
- `machine` - id, name, metadata, createdAt

I want to efficiently query metric_value based on the machine id, so far I have thought of three possible ways of doing it.

1. A left join i.e.

   ```
   SELECT timestamp, machine_id, metric_id, value, metadata 
   FROM metric_value 
   LEFT JOIN metric ON metric_id = metric.id 
   WHERE machine_id = 1;
   ```
2. Select all the metric ids that correspond to the target machine, then another select

   SELECT ..
   WHERE metric_id = ANY(:metricIds)
3. Add a `machine_id` column to the metric value

Is there a better way of doing this? I believe

1. The join will be slow when there are billions of metric values
2. Passing possibly thousands of metric ids in the `ANY()` will be slow
3. Unnecessary and redundant

Comment: Speed is measured in time, like milliseconds, seconds, etc. Not by opinions. Use EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for your SQL statements to get proper measurements. And query plans.

Comment: Also provide the complete table definitions including any indexes.

Comment: Just inner join the tables. This is a basic SQL problem and I think you are over thinking it